# What happened to Vidalia?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, vidalia, update, startup

I just updated Tor Browser bundle today. I opened it and was surprised to find no Vidalia control panel. Where did Vidalia go and how do I control the things that Vidalia did (bridges, start and stop Tor, etc.)?

Comment: I downloaded the same 3.x series its not included Vidalia,dont know Why not?Most of the important features missing from the new mid version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How do I control the things that Vidalia did?(bridges, start and stop tor)

Starting the TorBrowser starts (launches) Tor and closing the TorBrowser closes (exits) Tor.

All traffic from the TorBrowser is supposed to go through Tor.

Upon first launch of the extracted bundle you have two choices, either you connect to the Tor network directly or you change some configuration because you have to, like a forced proxy or a strict firewall or the requirement to use bridges.

After the TorBrowser is launched you see a green onion on the left to the URL bar. If you click it it gives you the option to have a "New Identity", which is more strict, compared to Vidalia, as it closes all open tabs.

It also allows you to add bridges. When you click "Open network settings" and then check "My ISP blocks connections to the Tor network" you can add your bridges.

Answer (score 11):

From the Tor Blog's [release post](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-bundle-35-released):

> In terms of user-facing changes from TBB 2.x, the 3.x series primarily features the replacement of Vidalia with a Firefox-based Tor controller called Tor Launcher. This has resulted in a vast decrease in startup times, and a vast increase in usability.

Vidalia is still [available for download](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) as Bridge/Relay/Exit bundles on Windows if you just want to use it for relaying and not browsing yourself.

Comment: And see also the FAQ entry for it, which includes a workaround for how to hook Vidalia up to TBB 3.5: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowserBundle3FAQ#WheredidtheworldmapVidaliago

Comment: Isn't Vidalia no longer supported for relaying? It might just be not supported on Linux and Mac.

Comment: Vidalia is still available for Windows 8, 7, Vista, and XP.

Comment: Cammy is right -- we've removed the bridge/relay/exit bundles from the download page too, since Vidalia has been unmaintained for years and pointing people to unmaintained software is dangerous. I'd love to have enough developers to do everything at once, but we don't.

Answer (score 2):

TBB version 3.5 or newer no longer employs Vidalia Control Panel. For more information and how to manually start Vidalia Control Panel if you want to, [read Roger Dingledine comment above](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1075/what-happened-to-vidalia#comment1164_1076).